# Deciding the initial view controller before app finish loading

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Hi I have a login view controller and my app storyboard views. The initial view controller points to the app dashboard. I am checking in my appDelegate application function if the user is logged in. After that I (re)set the correct UIViewController as the initial. Somehow the app always goes to the initial view controller and then says oops I need to go to login because the user is not logged in... How can I avoid this?

This is my current code.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if (settings.isLoggedIn())
    {
        let vc: AnyObject! = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc as? UIViewController
    } else {
        let vc: AnyObject! = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("login")
        self.window?.rootViewController = vc as? UIViewController
    }
})
```

Comment: Why the dispatch_async ?

Comment: @Leonardo that was actually a very good one, I thought xcode would complain about doing stuff with the interface without making sure its on the main thread. I removed it and the flow is really fluid now. I think that was my mistake.

Comment: It is a problem doing UI stuff on secondary threads, but the appDelegate methods are always called on the main thread, so you don't have to worry about that there

Answer (score 0):

how to check user logged in or not in below method in the appdelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool { 

  //check user logged or not, if true you can set the initial view controller given below 

  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let vc : UIViewController! = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("urcontroller") 

  let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0] ;
  window.rootViewController = vc;

  return true
}
```